# Ubuntu 15.10 not shutting down 64 bit

Tags: shutdown

I have a HP 15 r250tu with Pentium quad core 4gb ram. I am a windows user and installed ubuntu as a dual boot os. Now the ubuntu stuck at the splash screen when i shutdown or reboot and i have to force shut it. Not only ubuntu but elementryos, kali os, and lubuntu are showing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to bios setup and change "USB 3 setup on pre-install" to Disabled.